# Symfony2.2 Login from Database Error: "Bad Credentials"

Tags: security, symfony, authentication

I have roughly followed Symfony's [Security](http://symfony.com/doc/2.2/book/security.html) and [How to load Security Users from the Database](http://symfony.com/doc/2.2/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html) instructions with some small custom configurations but I can't login using the users I have in my database! The in_memory user works fine!

This is my security.yml:

```
jms_security_extra:
    secure_all_services: false
    expressions: true

security:
    encoders:
        NEWS\BlogBundle\Entity\Author: plaintext

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER


    providers:
        chain_provider:
            chain:
                providers: [user_db, in_memory]
        user_db:
            entity: { class: NEWSBlogBundle:Author , property: username }

        in_memory:
            memory:
                users:
                    admin: { password: adminpass, roles: [ 'ROLE_ADMIN' ] }

    firewalls:
        admin_area:
                    pattern:    ^/admin
                    http_basic: ~
        secured_area:
                    pattern:  ^/
                    anonymous: ~
                    form_login:
                        login_path: /Login
                        check_path: /login_check
                        username_parameter: username
                        password_parameter: password

                    logout:
                        path: /logout
                        target: /blog


    access_control:
         - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
         - { path: ^/newpost, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

And my Author.php (User) entity (I have removed the function annotations to make it shorter):

```
<?php

namespace NEWS\BlogBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;


/**
 * Author
 */
class Author implements \Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\AdvancedUserInterface, \Serializable

{
    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $Name;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $Surname;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $salt;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     */
    private $isActive;


    /**
     * @var \NEWS\BlogBundle\Entity\Category
     */
    private $category;





    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }


    public function setUsername($username)
    {
        $this->username = $username;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function setCategory(\NEWS\BlogBundle\Entity\Category $category = null)
    {
        $this->category = $category;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCategory()
    {
        return $this->category;
    }

    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->Name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->Name;
    }

    public function setSurname($surname)
    {
        $this->Surname = $surname;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getSurname()
    {
        return $this->Surname;
    }

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->isActive = true;
        $this-> salt = sha1(uniqid(null, true));
    }

    public function setSalt($salt)
    {
        $this->salt = $salt;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getSalt()
    {
        return $this->salt;
    }

    public function setIsActive($isActive)
    {
        $this->isActive = $isActive;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getIsActive()
    {
        return $this->isActive;
    }

    public function isAccountNonExpired()
    {
        // TODO: Implement isAccountNonExpired() method.
        return true;
    }

    public function isAccountNonLocked()
    {
        // TODO: Implement isAccountNonLocked() method.
        return true;
    }

    public function isCredentialsNonExpired()
    {
        return true;
    }
    public function isEnabled()
    {
            return $this->isActive;
    }
    public function getRoles()
    {
        return array('ROLE_USER');
    }

    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
        // TODO: Implement eraseCredentials() method.
    }
    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    private $posts;


    public function addPost(\NEWS\BlogBundle\Entity\Post $posts)
    {
        $this->posts[] = $posts;

        return $this;
    }

    public function removePost(\NEWS\BlogBundle\Entity\Post $posts)
    {
        $this->posts->removeElement($posts);
    }

    public function getPosts()
    {
        return $this->posts;
    }

    public function serialize()
    {
        return serialize(array(
            $this->id,
        ));
    }

    public function unserialize($serialized)
    {
        list (
            $this->id,
            ) = unserialize($serialized);
    }
}
```

This is my Login.html.twig

```
{# src/NEWS/BlogBundle/Resources/views/Page/Login.html.twig #}
{% extends 'NEWSBlogBundle::layout.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}Login Page{% endblock%}

{% block body %}
    <header>

    </header>

    {% if app.session.hasFlash('blogger-notice') %}
        <div class="blogger-notice">
            {{ app.session.flash('blogger-notice') }}
        </div>

    {% endif %}


    {% if error %}
        <div>{{ error.message }}</div>
    {% endif %}

    <form action="{{ path('login_check') }}" method="post">
        <label for="username">Username:</label>
        <input type="text" id="username" name="username" value="{{ last_username }}" />

        <label for="password">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" />


        <button type="submit">Login</button>
    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

Login controller:

```
public function LoginAction()
    {

        $request = $this->getRequest();
        $session = $request->getSession();

        // get the login error if there is one
        if ($request->attributes->has(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR)) {
            $error = $request->attributes->get(
                SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR
            );

        } else {
            $error = $session->get(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
            $session->remove(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
        }

        return $this->render(
            'NEWSBlogBundle:Page:Login.html.twig',
            array(
                // last username entered by the user
                'last_username' => $session->get(SecurityContext::LAST_USERNAME),
                'error'         => $error,
            )
        );
    }
```

and the function which builds my login form:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('username', 'text');
        $builder->add('password', 'password');
        return $builder->getForm();
    }
```

I've been trying to solve this for three days but have not been sucessful! I would really appreciate any help!

I don't know if the registration functions are needed too or not, I'm not including them right now since the question is long enough so far!

P.S: My login route intentionally starts with a capital letter and I am aware that I have removed the '_' from the user/pass parameteres, I did try changing them back to the original form but stil got the same error!

Comment: The error message "Bad credentials" is returned, when username/password do not match. From your security.yml I gather that you store passwords as plaintext, is this correct or are they encoded e.g. with md5, sha1 or something else?

Comment: I understand that but I don't uderstand why this is happening!
I am currently storing them as plaintext so I can trace what's happening. 
What I see in my database is a password which is NOT encoded and a salt which is encoded.

Comment: Check your app/logs/dev.log for error messages. To check if your salt is not causing any problems, temporarily change getSalt to return null: `getSalt() { return null; }` this way, you can make sure the salt is not the problem.

Answer (score 1):

input field should contain underscore

```
<input type="text" id="username" name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}" />

<input type="password" id="password" name="_password" />
```

looks funny, but faced it